# How do I use variables in a non-continuous ForEach loop

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I am trying to loop through a non-continuous `For Each`

[image]

The following works:

```
Sub Macro1()
    For Each C In ActiveSheet.Range("C5:G5,B3:F3,D7:H7").Cells
        Debug.Print C
    Next C
    'RESULT = 6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15
End Sub
```

The ranges however do change so I need to address them with variables.
I tried the following but none of these did work:

1st try

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("C5:G5").Cells
    Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F3").Cells
    Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("D7:H7").Cells
    For Each C In ActiveSheet.Range(rng1, rng2, rng3).Cells
        Debug.Print C
    Next C
    'RESULT = "wrong number of arguments...
End Sub
```

2nd try

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("C5:G5").Cells, ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F3").Cells, ActiveSheet.Range("D7:H7").Cells)
    For Each C In rng
        Debug.Print C
    Next C
    'RESULT = "run-time error 424
End Sub
```

The desired outcome is like the first example I provided but rather than fixed ranges I need to return the same outcome with variables.

**UPDATE**
@BDra provided a working solution for the above.
However applying the same in a bit different setting does not work.

[image]

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    V = 13
    Set rng = Union(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & V & ":B17"), ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B" & V))
    For Each C In rng
        Debug.Print C
    Next C
    'RESULT = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
End Sub
```

The desired outcome should be `11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Comment: Re your update, I think the issue is that Union creates a single new range. You don't get to "arrange" the cells within that range; the `For Each` loop will run through them sequentially. For better control over the process, and to be able to arrange the sequence as you see fit, I recommend that you take a second look at @Matthias Fuglsang-Damgaard's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second try is pretty close, but `Intersect` yields Nothing since the three ranges do not intersect. The run-time error is triggered because `rng = Nothing`.

What you are after is `Union`:

```
Set rng = Union(ActiveSheet.Range("C5:G5").Cells, ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F3").Cells, ActiveSheet.Range("D7:H7").Cells)
```

With that one edit your second version should work.

Comment: Thanks BDra, that worked just great. I updated my question because there is a case in which it does not work. May I ask you to have look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer BDra has given solves your problem.

**Alternativ solution**

As an alternativ solution. I would suggest in this situation to isolate the for loop in its own sub and parse the ranges as arguments. One of the benefits of this is that you can now have an infinite amount of ranges going through the loop and your code will still be nice and clean :-)

```
Sub Main()
    NextSub ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F3")
    NextSub ActiveSheet.Range("C5:G5")
    NextSub ActiveSheet.Range("D7:H7")
End Sub
Sub NextSub(rng as Range)
    For Each C In rng.Cells
        Debug.Print C
    Next C
End Sub
```